# C casting to a structure

Tags: c

What is the purpose of the following code:

```
#define LPC_ADC  ((LPC_ADC_T   *) LPC_ADC_BASE)
```

LPC_ADC_T is a structure holding some constants.

```
typedef struct {                                
    __IO uint32_t CTRL;                     
    __I  uint32_t RESERVED0;
    __IO uint32_t SEQ_CTRL[ADC_SEQB_IDX + 1];   
    __IO uint32_t SEQ_GDAT[ADC_SEQB_IDX + 1];   
    __I  uint32_t RESERVED1[2];
    __I  uint32_t DR[9];                        
    __I  uint32_t RESERVED2[3];
    __IO uint32_t THR_LOW[2];                   
    __IO uint32_t THR_HIGH[2];              
    __IO uint32_t CHAN_THRSEL;              
    __IO uint32_t INTEN;                        
    __IO uint32_t FLAGS;                    
    __IO uint32_t TRM;                          
} LPC_ADC_T;
```

LPC_ADC_BASE is a constant.

Is it simply casting the constant number LPC_ADC_BASE to a structure?

Comment: Suggest setting the type of the 'LPC_ADC_BASE' as a pointer to a LPC_ADC_T instance, when it was first defined; rather than as an 'after thought' as is being done here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After that cast you can access the registers like

```
uint32_t something = 0xf5; //whatever
LPC_ADC->CTRL = something;
```

The following code

```
#define LPC_ADC  ((LPC_ADC_T   *) LPC_ADC_BASE)
```

means:
Treat LPC_ADC_BASE as an address of LPC_ADC_T type structure and allow to access it using name LPC_ADC

Answer (score 1):

It's casting the integer value to a pointer to the structure.

The point is to allow access by name for each register in that particular device. It depends on the layout of the `struct`'s members being very compact and predictable, often you use compiler-specific options to ensure that.

Answer (score 0):

It's casting the constant number to a pointer to an address.

It assumes that at the memory of your program contains a `LPC_ADC_T` at the address `LPC_ADC_BASE`

This is a method used when you know the address of a struct/method at compiletime.